# Adding domain to have dropdown box in Attribute Table using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, domains, subtype

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/as_a_stand_alone_feature_class/002200000005000000/
Line 23 - To associate a domain with this field, click the field next to Domain, click the drop-down arrow to see a list of the domains that apply to this field type, then click the domain.

i am trying to get where, in the attribute table, I have a dropdown box.  I follow the instructions in here and I am getting knowhere.  What am I not doing, is there more to do then what this states?  I am using ArcView 10.1

I go to the FEATURE CLASS PROPERTIES, under FIELDS, I have the field name "STATUS" and text.  Then I go to SUBTYPES.  The subtype field shows , what do I need to add to that field?  I can't click anywhere in those boxes.

I am just looking to have the dropdown boxes under status  "producing", "leased" etc...

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check for a residual schema lock. I just spent 2 hours frittering with this exact same problem.

Comment: You should also check that you are not in an editing session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is the gdb the featureclass lives in does not have any domains defined.
Without any domains in the GDB, the feature class fields doesnt have any to display.

Try creating some in the GDB:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_new_coded_value_domain/001s00000004000000/

Comment: You will also need to click on the field in the feature class properties in order to see the properties of that field and choose whether to use a domain.  If no domains are seen, check that data type of domain and field you wish to use it with match.

Comment: @Polygeo and khibma - both correct thank you!  something simple I overlooked.  Thank YOu.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to click on the field in the feature class properties in order to see the properties of that field and choose whether to use a domain.

If no domains are seen, check that data type of domain and field you wish to use it with match.