# Drop-down not showing on attribute table after I set a GDB domain?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, domains

I created a file GDB with various feature classes that already have data in them.  I then set up a domain to the GDB, and when I open the attribute tables of each of my feature classes there is no-drop down to choose from the coded domain. I also tried adding a new field within the attribute table and there is still no coded domain.  Is this because my feature classes were pre-populated with data?

Comment: did you try, saving , closing and opening catalogue/ArcMap again?

Comment: Did you Start Editing?

Comment: Yes, I added a new field. Then started an edit session.

Comment: I also tried saving, restarting ArcMap...also tried restarting my computer and none seem to work.

Comment: Since the gdb already has data, you might try setting it up in a blank feature class first and then importing your data.  To speed this up you could create a schema from the existing FC.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that as I'm thinking this may be the issue

Comment: If you look at the Related questions in the right hand sidebar of the web client there seem to be some other reports which may offer other useful suggestions e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35574/adding-domain-to-have-dropdown-box-in-attribute-table-using-arcgis-for-desktop?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did something wrong.please follow my example step by step:

1. Create a Domain in GeoDatabase [Step1][[image: http://i.imgur.com/kZQml4e.jpg]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v1G4.jpg)
2. Add Filed in your layer(target) Right-click on Layer and select properties in Geodatabase when opened feature class properties Select Filed Tab and add new filed name and choose type of field (exactly same domain type)[step2][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Lyq.jpg)
3. Open layer attributes, right-click on layer in table of content and select open attribute table, after that add new field.
   [Step 3. in other way][[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD80Q.jpg)
4. when open attributes is still open start editor, Finally you can see code values is dropping down for new filed, they are code value you entered in step 1,
   [Step 4][[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhD0S.jpg)

Note that the domain entry might not appear if the target field is not
of the same data type as the domain.